# How to use AJAX with Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to create a particular functionality with Wordpress. Simply put, I have items with woocommerce and each of them has attributes like:

Print color
Color
Sheet width
(These are the attributes of only 1 product, the others may have completely different attributes such as shoe color or size)

Now, I thought it best to create attributes for my woocommerce product and calculate the variants. ALL products will have: Shipping time and quantity, compared to the characteristics that the user enters with the woocommerce drop-down menus I would like to obtain Shipping time, quantity and price of the variant.

Now, my problem is actually creating the table and lately.

A site that does exactly what I ask is:

https://stampadalweb.com/prodotti/sottobicchieri-personalizzate-di-carta/

just choose a product at random and you will immediately see the table with the various characteristics

I'm looking at how to use AJAX and it seems like a good solution, but if anyone has a way to structure a better solution let me know!. I found the following event that captures when the value of one of the woocommerce dropdowns are changed:

```
jQuery(document).on('change.wc-variation-form', 'form.variations_form', function(event) {
});
```

Even if I change the value of a dropdown once I get the result of the event 4 times, now, I would like to calculate the table with respect to the values of the dropdown menus and pass them to the backend to obtain shipping time, quantity and price. My code is as follows:

```
jQuery(document).on('change.wc-variation-form', 'form.variations_form', function(event) {

console.log("dropdown value changed");

       var filterVar = jQuery(this).val();
       jQuery.ajax({
         url: '/test/wp-content/themes/storefront/js/func.php',
         type: "POST",
         date: {
action: 'testfunc',
           filter: filterVar
         },
         success: function(response) {
console.log(response);
           jQuery("#results").html(response);
         }
       });
     });
```

file func.php

```
<?php

require_once( '/home/customer/www/crisartigrafiche.com/public_html/wp-load.php' );

add_action('wp_ajax_testFunc', 'ql_testFunc'); 
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_testFunc', 'ql_testFunc');        

function testFunc() {
    
wp_send_json_success(123);
    wp_die();
}

?>
```

Problems:

- console.log(response) and var filterVar = jQuery(this).val(); they give me an empty string even though I indicate wp_send_json_success(123)
- Even if I set filter: 10 (therefore a fixed value) I don't get anything in the backend

How to reproduce the problem:
Create a product on woocommerce and put up some variations, maybe create 6 attributes in total. Now, make sure that if you choose 4 attributes the other 2 must be taken with respect to those 4 previously chosen, how do you do it?

The expected behavior is to send wp_send_json_success(123); to the frontend and have it print and then try to do it with some dynamic data

What did I do?

- With AJAX I invented everything, I tried to put admin-ajax.php as the url and then insert the function but it doesn't seem to work, create a code snippet with the appropriate plugin (and it isn't executed even by mistake) and Finally, create a php file that contains only the code I have shared
- Then I temporarily disabled a .htaccess filter that doesn't allow running .php files on the server just for some testing

Comment: To use the filter `wp_ajax_nopriv_testFunc` you will have to send the ajax request to the built-in ajax url. Usually `/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php`. If you send the `action` parameter with value `testFunc` your function will get triggered.